# Sistema de usuarios ambiente Node, Express e GraphQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, express.js, graphql

Olá, mundo! Estou estudando GraphQL e estou tendo um problema com essa mutation...

`var schema = buildSchema('
    type userAccount {
        firstName: String!
        lastName: String!
        mobileNumber: String 
        email: String 
        password: String!
    }
    type Mutation {
        createAccount(
            firstName: String!, 
            lastName: String!,
            mobileNumber: String,
            email: String,
            password: String!
        ): userAccount
    }
');
var root = {
    createAccount: ({firstName, lastName, mobileNumber, email, password}) => {
// AccountModel.create é um model do sequelize que registra os dados, isso funciona, mas a mutation retorna null
        AccountModel.create({ 
            firstName,
            lastName,
            mobileNumber,
            email,
            password
        })
    }
};`

// Então em localhost:3000/graphiql eu faço a mutation e ela retorna null(Deveria retornar a conta que acabei de registrar)
[image: GraphiQL]
[image: Running nodemon]
[image: db]

Comment: Veja [esse post da própria documentação do GraphQL](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/object-types/).

Comment: Ah, e, no código original, no `buildSchema`, você colocou aspas simples (`'`) ou acento grave (`\``)?

Comment: No código original eu usei crases( ` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui solucionar o problema...
... faltava apenas um 'return' na função 
    
`var root = {
    createAccount: ({firstName, lastName, mobileNumber, email, password}) => {
        return AccountModel.create({ 
            firstName,
            lastName,
            mobileNumber,
            email,
            password
        })
    }
};`